# The projection map from a topological group to its homogeneous space is always an open map

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

Let E be a topological group and let F be a closed subgroup of E. Define an equivalence relation in E as follows: two elements $a, b$ of E are said to equi- valent iff there is an element $f \in F$ such that a$f$=b. Thus the elements of E are divided into disjoint equivalence classes called the left cosets of F in E. The left coset containing $a \in E$ is obviously the closed set $aF$ of E and we obtain a quotient space B = E/F whose elements are left cosets of F in E and a natural projection $p:E \rightarrow B$. which maps $a \in E$ onto the left coset $aF \in B. B = E/F $is called the quotient space of E by F; it will be called simply a homogeneous space.

Then how to prove that $p$ is an open map?
First of all I don't know how what will be the image of an open set under $p$.

Comment: What is $p^{-1}\bigl(p(U)\bigr)$ for $U \subset E$?

Comment: what's the topology in the quotient space?

Comment: @DanielFischer $p^{-1}(p(U)) = \cup_{g \in F} gU$

Comment: $$\bigcup_{g\in F} Ug = \bigcup_{u\in U} uF$$ actually. Is that open in $E$?

Comment: Oh yes. thanks for correction. Yeah it is open(being union of open set)

Comment: Wait. I don't think so as F is closed in E, so is uF. And arbitrary union of closed set?

Comment: Yes, $uF$ is closed. But $Ug$ is open and hence $p^{-1}(p(U))$ is open when $U$ is open.

Comment: Ok, but then how $p(U)$ is open ?

Comment: Look at the definition of the quotient topology. $W \subset E/F$ is open if and only if …

Comment: Ah, thanks I got it! $U$ is open in $X$ iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open where $f :X \rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map and hence $p(U)$ is open above

Answer (score 2):

A set U in E/F is open if it's inverse image under p is open in E ( This comes from the definition of quotient topology.)
Let V be open in E. We need to show that p(V) is open in E/F or equivalently, inverse image of p(V) is open in E. Let this set be called S. Firstly,see that p(V) = { v+ H : v \in V} .
Now S  is the set of all x in E such that p(x) is in p(V).This means x + H = v + H for some v in V and thus x - v is in H for some v in V. This finally means that x belongs to the coset v + H for some v in V.  This holds for every v in V and hence the set S is same as union of v + H for every v in V. And this set can be rearranged as union of V + h for every h in H. The set V + h is open as it is the image of under translation map v + h. Hence the complete union is open and thus S is open. Hence p(V) is open.